# Remove extra Divs & css from bokeh controls

Tags: bokeh

Example about the usage of file-select

```
<div class="bk-root" id="d767cfd5-1265-4adb-a0ce-f865e2640394" data-root-id="1001"> I need to remove this
<div class="bk myinput" style="position: relative; display: block; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 22px; margin: 5px;"> and remove this
<input type="file" accept=".xer"> and keep this
</div>
</div>
```

I need to remove the surrounding tags with their styling and keep the control only
Thanks